# Javascript ES6 passing parameter between double extended classes react ag grid

Tags: javascript, class, oop, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**I'm using React with Ag Grid and ES6, and this is a master-detail feature in Ag Grid.**

suppose I have 2 classes that have the same `functionTest` to be called.

```
    class children extends (Parent,React.Component){
           constructor(value){
           super(test);
           this.functionTest= this.functionTest.bind(this);
           }

           functionTest(){
           return super.functionTest();
           }

           render (){
           <AgGridReact
             ...
                   onGridReady={this.onTestFunction.bind(this)}
             ...
           />
           }

   class MyApp extends React.Component {
   constructor(test) {
           super();
           this.test=test;
            }

           functionTest(){
           return this.test;
           }

           render() {
           <AgGridReact
             ...
                    onGridReady={this.functionTest.bind(this)}
                    fullWidthCellRendererFramework= {children}
             ...
            />
            }
```

I have some success in calling in `functionTest` from `MyApp` via `onGridReady` props, but can not if initiated from `children`. I can also if I want to re-write the function in `children` to make it works, but that will be redundant ( I have a lot of similar functions ).

I also double extend children from Parent and React.Component and seems got no error.

**My question is how I can call functionTest from children living inside MyApp?**

Answer (score 0):

```
void calculate(Person p){
    p.getCalculableValue();
}
```